# What is the difference between using "de" and "que" for the English word "to"?

Tags: traducción, gramática

Here are two examples where `de` and `que` are meant to translate to `to` in English:

`¿Dónde tengo que dejar los documentos?` = Where do I have to leave the documents?

`Es imposible de saber` = It is impossible to know.

Both `que` and `de` mean `to` in these sentences. My question is what is the difference such that one must be used over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I need to say that's a really good question that Spanish learners ask often.

Well when you say in Spanish `¿Dónde tengo que dejar los documentos?` you're actually asking a question: Where **do I have** to leave the documents?. It's an obligation.

Whereas, **es imposible de saber** it's an informative sentence, I mean, you're saying that **It's** impossible to know, without any reason.

So the main difference between `Que` and `De` is they are used depending the verbs and the context of the sentence. For example:

If say something that I have to do, let's say, my homeworks I'll say:

> Tengo que hacer mis deberes (I have to do my homework)

But if I say something that's not an obligation; a normal sentence it will be, for example:

> Las respuestas a mis deberes son imposibles de saber (It's impossible to know the answers to my homework)

As you can see, the `que` element is mostly used to say something you **have to do** and the `de` element is used for informative sentences. Hope it helped.

Comment: I tried to edit the answer to correct the sentence, as it's wrong, but it seems that the edit didn't go through the moderation queue.
The correct sentence would be either: "Es imposible saber las respuestas de mis deberes" or Son imposibles de saber las respuestas de mis deberes (equivalent to: "Las respuestas de mis deberes son imposibles de saber, which sounds more normal"

Comment: What about `para` in `Tienes mucho para ofrecer`?

Answer (score 2):

That's certainly a tricky question, and probably what's throwing you off is that "de" in your second example is attached to "imposible". It is used as a connector between the adjective (imposible, difícil, fácil, rápido) and the verb (in infinitive tense) that it's affecting.

However, in your first example, that "que" is a conjunction that links the main sentence (¿Dónde tengo XXXXX?) with the subordinate sentence (...que dejar los documentos).

Their purposes are completely different, and it's a coincidence (as far as I know) that the second "de" in english as to.

Don't try and draw a relation between them because they're translated the same. If I knew more about english, I could probably tell why "to" is used in both, but don't let that coincidence make you think there is any relation.

I hope I could clarify this up.