# When should one use "para" for the English word "to"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, gramática

This is an extension of the question [What is the difference between using "de" and "que" for the English word "to"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/5268/what-is-the-difference-between-using-de-and-que-for-the-english-word-to)

Consider the sentence "You have one minute to choose":

> Tienes un minuto para elegir.

Taking the information from the other question I would've assumed that `para` would be `de` because it is an informative statement. I don't think `que` can be used because it's not an obligation (I think).

So why is `para` being used? And can you flesh out the differences between `que` and `para` as well.

Comment: In English one could also say "You have one minute for to choose" which is a more direct translation from Spanish, but in English it's a bit archaic.

Comment: "For to choose" is incorrect. You could perhaps say "for choosing" but "for to choose" is ungrammatical. In English prepositions simply are not followed by *to*-infinitives.

Answer (score 2):

If you use **de** in the sentence above, wouldn't it change the meaning to:

```
You have one minute of choice
```

It doesn't make much scene, but consider this:

```
Tienes un minuto de paz / You have one minute of peace
```

Here **para** is used to denote purpose, destination or need, while **de** is used to indicate possession. 
I think this difference can also be clearly seen in those two examples:

```
Tengo una copa de vino / I have a cup of wine
Tengo una copa para vino / I have a cup for wine
```

They both have different meaning and one cannot be a substitute for the other.  
  
As for **que** I can't really think of an example where it can be confused with **para**.  
You may check this link http://spanish.about.com/od/pronouns/a/que_relative_pronouns.htm and try to memorize which preposition is used in what situation.

Answer (score 1):

It's a peculiarity of the English language that you have 40 minutes **for** lunch, but 40 minutes **to** eat it.

In Spanish we use **for** (*para*) always, that's all. *40 minutos para el almuerzo* y *40 minutos para comerlo*.

Comment: The reason "to" is used in the second case is because it's part of the *to*-infinitive "to eat." Unlike Spanish, English frequently uses such infinitives as adjectival modifiers.